# Plant Identification Help

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image]

Can someone help me identify this plant? Flowers bloom in summer, then red seeds form afterwards.  Leaf length is about 10 inches max.  I live in Southern California and it is grown in a container under my patio.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be **Scadoxus Puniceus**, also known as the **Paintbrush Lily** (not to be confused with other species with the same common name). The dutch originally cultivated scadoxus puniceus, and your specimen could be one of several hybrids of the original.

[Dave's Garden](https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/64258/) has plenty of pictures of the species. He didn't have any fruit at the same stage of ripeness as yours, but the likeness is still rather compelling.

[image: Fruit (different season)]
[image: Dozens of flowers]
[image: Close up flower head]

For a slightly more reliable source (if a little older), the [South African Medical Journal](https://journals.co.za/content/m_samj/75/2/AJA20785135_8991) also identifies Scadoxus Puniceus in a study of accidental poisonings by herbal medicine. The flower might be a touch wider than yours, but you almost certainly still have a **Scadoxus**, and within-species variations can easily account for such a small difference.
[image: Screenshot from South African Medical Journal]

**Copyright Disclaimer:** All included photos would typically fall under fair use due to their limited scope compared to the original work and due to their non-commercial use as a benefit to the public. If any of the copyright holders disagree, feel free to contact me so we can resolve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the biology SE and congrats on your first answer, that I believe to be correct. However, on BiologySE it is required that you substantiate your claim with evidence, for example a picture or a description why it is this species.

Comment: @RHA Thank you. Is this more like what you had in mind?